# Drawing histogram on a ruled graph sheet. Help me with this

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, nodes-near-coords, histogram

I would like to draw this histogram (see the attached image) on a ruled graph sheet. So far, I have the MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width = 1.00*\textwidth,
height = 8cm,
ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
bar width=1pt,
ymajorgrids = true,
ybar interval=1.0,
xlabel = {Months},
ylabel = {Amount of Rainfall (cm)},
symbolic x coords={Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec},
ymin=0,
]
\addplot[style={blue,fill=green}] 
coordinates {
(Jan,0.6) (Feb,1)
(Mar,2) (Apr,3.2) 
(May,4) (Jun,4) 
(Jul,4.5) (Aug,3) 
(Sep,5) (Oct,5) 
(Nov,0.7) (Dec,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

[image: Histogram on a Ruled Graph Sheet]

Please, I need the following help:

1. The last value for December (Dec) is not displaying. I want this to display.
2. I need the plot to have minor gridlines as in the attached image.
3. I will like the bars to be a bit transparent so that the gridlines can still be seen through.
4. If possible, to remove the bounding box of the axis plot in the MWE from displaying. In fact, I need the graph sheet to resemble that in the attached image

Comment: In this `pgfplots` package is your friend. So, see the first example on the page 88 of *pgfplots manual*. This example can be relative easy adapt to what you like to have. In the first attempt don't bother with image background, this we can help you add when you will have your histogram. So far your question is "do.it-instead-me" ... what is liked here.

Comment: Okay, let me try it again. Though I have tried it before and got no success in making it look like the above. Regarding the example on page 88, the nodes on the x axis are intervals, but this one is symbolic coordinates

Comment: symbolic coordinates  -- page 386 -- just do ctrl-F to search the pdf doc

Comment: I've tried my best. See the MWE that I attached. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- For Dec, add a dummy value with zero to the `symbolic x coords`, say `a`.

2- For a minor grid lines, use `grid style` and `major grid style` options in `axis` environment, like:

```
grid=major,
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!60},
minor tick num=5
```

Also add

```
xmin=Jan,
xmax=a,
ymin=0,
ymax=5
```

3- For tranparency, use `opacity` option in `addplot`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width = 1.00*\textwidth,
height = 8cm,
ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
bar width=1pt,
%ymajorgrids = true,
ybar interval=1.0,
xlabel = {Months},
ylabel = {Amount of Rainfall (cm)},
symbolic x coords={Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,a}, % Add a zero valued extra coord. for Dec.
grid=major,
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!60},
minor tick num=5,
xmin=Jan,
xmax=a,
ymin=0,
ymax=5,
]
\addplot[style={blue,fill=green!30,opacity=0.5}] 
coordinates {
(Jan,0.6) (Feb,1)
(Mar,2) (Apr,3.2) 
(May,4) (Jun,4) 
(Jul,4.5) (Aug,3) 
(Sep,5) (Oct,5) 
(Nov,0.7) (Dec,0) (a,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you greatly.

Comment: You only need one `grid` option. If you use `both`, then `major` is not needed because it's included in the former along with `grid=minor`.